# Unable to pass values into required input fields using properties file during Mobile App testing

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, appium

I am testing an Android Mobile App using Cucumber features, Java, Appium and TestNG. 
After writing feature file and defining the steps, **how to call properties file which consists of Xpath and how to test the application.**

The steps I followed till now:

1. Installed Java, Eclipse IDE, Appium and JARs required for Selenium, Cucumber and TestNG.
2. Connected the device and done with the required steps like connecting the devices using Appium.
3. I am now able to open my testing application but unable to enter the data into required input fields.

**I would like to know the reason why the locators are not picking up.**

If possible can anyone provide me with the sample java script for a Mobile App TestNG.

Comment: Can u add the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass your locators by using properties files, it's not the right way to do that.
Please use page factory model and locate your elements by using @FindBy("locator").

Sorry for adding this as answer, did that by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very difficult to give solution/suggestion without any logs or code snippet.
It would be easy if you can provide them so.